# How do I share variables/facts between Molecule Playbooks?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, molecule

I'm trying to share a variable between my `converge` step and my `cleanup` step of my Molecule. Since both playbooks are being run on the same host, I figure I can use facts to cache the variable as a fact.

In `converge.yml`:

```yaml
- name: Cache some variable
    set_fact:
      cacheable: yes
      my_fact: "howdy, world"
```

In `cleanup.yml`:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_fact }}"
```

and in my top-level `ansible.cfg` I specify:

```ini
[defaults]
gathering = smart
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/facts_cache
fact_caching_timeout = 7200
```

I first run `molecule converge` and then I run `molecule cleanup` I'm getting the error: (reformatted)

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
fatal: [cluster-toolchain]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option
with an undefined variable. The error was: 'my_fact' is undefined
The error appears to be in '{REDACTED}/cleanup.yml': line 5, column 7, but may be
elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}
```

I've got some guesses, like maybe Molecule doesn't see my top level `ansible.cfg` or something.

Anyway, I was hoping for some help here. Maybe there is a better way to share the variable in Molecule world.

Answer (score 1):

Molecule is a tool to test Ansible roles. It is not targeted to execute Ansible playbooks. Usual command is `ansible-playbook`.

Molecule cannot not read your `ansible.cfg` with fact caching settings. If you want to make your commands working, add settings in `molecule.yml`:

```yaml
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  config_options:
    defaults:
      gathering: smart
      fact_caching: jsonfile
      fact_caching_connection: /tmp/facts_cache
      fact_caching_timeout: 7200
```

Then `molecule converge` followed by `molecule cleanup` gives:

```yaml
PLAY [Cleanup] ************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vagrant-instance] => {
    "msg": "howdy, world"
}
```